# Add a Section Separator Between UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The first one(left) is my design and the second one(right) is what I have achieved still now. One difference is that for the second image I don't have the separator line like the first one. In `viewForFooterInSection` i have already tried many existing solutions to show separator lines but didn't get the exact solution. I need the separator line at the end of the last row of the first and second sections with some space.

[image]

Here is my code -

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return secName.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "APHomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! APHomeTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.cellTitle.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.secName[section]
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let headerFrame = tableView.frame
    
    let title = UILabel()
    title.frame =  CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: headerFrame.size.width-20, height: 40)
    title.font = UIFont.SFBoldFont(ofSize: 14)//UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 30)!
    title.text = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    title.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.19, alpha: 1.0)//UIColor(red: 34/255.0, green: 141/255.0, blue: 183/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    let headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerFrame.size.width, height: headerFrame.size.height))
    headerView.addSubview(title)
    
    return headerView
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let section = indexPath.section
    return 70
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a little change

***turn***

[image: 111]

***to***

[image: 4444]

Comment: Didn't understand clearly, could you please give a brief. @dengST30

Comment: see the former section footer and the line as a whole, as the new section footer

Comment: It can be done for the footer but not for the header because the header row will be increased.

Comment: only one header, `tableView.tableHeaderView` . A header per section, `viewForHeaderInSection `

Comment: So what is `because the header row will be increased`